# geom_boxplot in ggplot2 in R is not working correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large dataset that is tidy and it is formatted as such

```
year Risk_score
2019 a
2019 b
2019 c
2020 d
2020 e
2020 f
2021 g
2021 h 
2021 i
```

where the letters are different values

whenever I try to use `geom_boxplot` to visualize the data it just either shows me a big diagonal line or a straight line

```
senderoriskyy %>% ggplot(aes(x = factor(Risk_score), y = year)) + geom_boxplot()
```

I've tried changing the variables to factors and numeric variables but it just keeps giving me the same result

output from running

```
dput(head(senderoriskyy, 10))
```

```
structure(list(year = c("Risk_Score_in_2020", "Risk_Score_in_2021", 
"Risk_Score_in_2020", "Risk_Score_in_2021", "Risk_Score_in_2019", 
"Risk_Score_in_2020", "Risk_Score_in_2021", "Risk_Score_in_2019", 
"Risk_Score_in_2020", "Risk_Score_in_2021"), Risk_score = c(`0.33040000000000003` = 0.3304, 
`0.30687999999999999` = 0.30688, `2.9` = 2.9, `0.46500000000000002` = 0.465, 
`1.16256` = 1.16256, `0.32256000000000001` = 0.32256, `0.27776000000000001` = 0.27776, 
`0.19488` = 0.19488, `26.905999999999999` = 26.906, `23.581` = 23.581
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: When I make some fake data it works ok. `senderoriskyy <- data.frame(year = sample(2015:2021, 100, replace = TRUE),  Risk_score = sample(letters[1:10], 100, replace = TRUE))`.   Could you please include the output of running `dput(head(senderoriskyy, 10))` so we can confirm the data structure?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the output of running `dput(head(senderoriskyy, 10))`  Looks like pasting error in comment with output, btw, missing some bits.

Comment: i've edited the question to show that output

Comment: I suspect you want `aes(y = Risk_score, x = year)`

Comment: yes, i think either way may work but y = Risk_score and x = year

Comment: If you want horizontal boxplots (where score is horizontal), you may want `geom_boxplot(orientation = "y")`